# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking Data Issue

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

The Google Analytics example code for tracking ecommerce in the new analytics.js instead of ga.js gives data in the fields where I have $product['name'] etc.

The code below currently doesn't work and I'm not 100% sure it's pulling the correct information onpage as this is what is shown in the page source instead of 'id': '{1455}', it's showing 'id': '{$order_query['order_id']}',. We're using Opencart 1.5.5.1.

Is this the correct code?
Are the $price, $product['name'] sections correct?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-21397982-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{$order_query['order_id']}',
  'revenue': '{$price}',
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '$order_query['order_id']',
  'name': '{$product['name']}',
  'sku': '{$product['model']}',
  'price': '{$product['price']}',
  'quantity': '{$product['quantity']}',
  'currency': 'GBP'
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your raw php code should be echoing out the values in to the JavaScript

```
'id': '{<?php echo $order_query['order_id']; ?> }',
```

what you are sending to Google Anlayitcs now is the

id of "`{$order_query['order_id']}`" which is a text string and not going to work.

Comment: Ah, so if I change everything to have `<?php echo` before and `; ?>` after it should work?

Comment: cross your fingers and give it a try :)  I don't know your system but it looks like someone put raw php values in there.

Comment: Now I'm getting `  'price': '{}',` in the page source. Does this mean the php values are wrong? Where can I find the correct ones?

Comment: Yes probably means the php values are empty.  The correct ones should be part of your system.  Contact who ever created the ecommerce system for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code

```html
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-21397982-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{$order_query['order_id']}',
  'revenue': '{$price}',
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '$order_query['order_id']',
  'name': '{$product['name']}',
  'sku': '{$product['model']}',
  'price': '{$product['price']}',
  'quantity': '{$product['quantity']}',
  'currency': 'GBP'
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Surly Opencart using tpl file for template. and this code suppose to work.
since it is not working then try below code.

```html
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-21397982-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '<?php echo $order_query['order_id'];?>',
  'revenue': <?php echo $price;?>,
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '<?php echo $order_query['order_id'];?>',
  'name': '<?php echo $product['name'];?>',
  'sku': '<?php echo $product['model'] ;?>',
  'price': <?php echo $product['price'];?>,
  'quantity': <?php echo $product['quantity']};?>,
  'currency': 'GBP'
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

and if there is problem with your variables then you should go through  this link http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/ecommerce-tracking-in-opencart-2-3/ 
this might be useful .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this would be to use an extension already made. It will save you messing about and should work straight away. There's loads on the store. I've tried a few analytics extensions for opencart but the best and easiest to work with in my experience is this one: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4496 It took me about 10 minutes to set up and I had ecommerce and site data in my analytics account the same day